# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: php, laravel

`I have looked through the forums and not found anything to help with this issue. The weird thing is that I have the exact same files on another pc and run through xampp and for some reason this is giving me this error. I am running a laravel project and when I try to go to one of the pages this happens.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


// Route::get('/', 
//     ['as' => 'home',
//     'middleware' => 'role:admin',
//     'uses' => 'PageController@index']);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', ['page_title' => 'Internation Revolving Doors']);
});

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth/login', array("page_title" => "Login"));    
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $data = array(
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        );

    if (Auth::attempt($data))
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}

public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}

public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth/register', array('page_title' => 'Sign Up'));
}

public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $validator = $this->validator($data);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect('auth/register');
    }
    else
    {
        $user = $this->create($data);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if ($data['architect']){
            // Assign the role
        }
        else{
            // Assign the role
        }
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post some code

Comment: Please show us your `routes.php` file and tell us what URL you are experiencing the error on...

Comment: I apologize i thought i put the code there. But it is there now. And all the routes I try to go to are just giving me the same error. I put the controller below the routes to show you.

Comment: @Moppo the code is there now!

Comment: @Jamesking56 the code is there now!

Comment: Have you got route caching enabled?

Comment: You have a .htaccess set up?

Comment: Sorry I do not really know what you mean by route caching James, and I am also not sure what .htaccess is Tim.

Comment: @Tim here is my .htacess   
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Alright. And you said it's working on another machine? What is the difference between these machines?

Comment: getting same error.. is there anyone short out this issue ?